# The usual ordering of R is not order isomorphic to c??

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to understand the term "cofinality". I am reading about it in here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofinality.
It went rather well until I encountered this statement: "The usual ordering of R is not order isomorphic to c, the cardinality of the real numbers".

Is there any "usual" order which is defined on $2^{\aleph_0}$, other the usual ordering of $\mathbb{R}$?

Thank you!
Shir

Comment: Cardinal numbers are particular ordinal numbers, they are well-ordered. $\mathbb{R}$ with its usual order is not well-ordered.

Answer (score 1):

A cardinal number is by definition an initial ordinal, and therefore has a natural order on it, indeed a well-order. The usual ordering on $\mathbb{R}$ is very far from being a well-order.